# Angular JS Modal Window functioning

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, window

Just a beginner to Angular JS. Struggling with a modal window scenario. Following is a simple scenario in my application:

A landing home page which has a "Add New" button, clicking on the Add New button opens a modal window which has got a lengthy form. Following are my questions/issues that I am facing:

1. First time click of the "Add New" button opens the modal window. Once you close it using top right corner "Cross" image and then reopens then it won't open at all. I have gone through several threads on Stack overflow already posted but nothing helped really. Also, have already searched and read a lot on the angular documentation but the Angular documentation seems to be intended for professionals with Angular JS.
2. Secondly, I would need assistance in making my modal window functional. I have a lengthy form on the modal window. There is a "Save" button, "Close" button & "Delete" button. I would like to know specifically,

   - that where am I supposed to put the form tag - in the main landing page template html (home.html) or in the modal window template html (createNewRI.html) ? And how do I handle the form in the modal window ?
   - How do I make sure the confusing "scope" thing is taken care of whenever Save button is clicked on my Modal window form. How to

Landing Page Template (home.html)

```
{..............
..............
<div class="pull-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-with-text" ng-click="addModalOpen = true">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add New Item
  </button>
</div>
............
..........
<form name="createRIForm" class="form-horizontal col-sm-6">
  <div ng-controller="AddCtrl" class="modal fade" ng-include="'createNewRI.html'" ng-class="{'in' : $parent.addModalOpen}">
</div></form>
.......
....... End of the main landing page i.e., home.html }
```

Modal Window template html (createNewRI.html)

```
...............
...........
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="$parent.addModalOpen = false">&times;    </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create New Item</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...modal body contains around 25 fields ....
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
    </div>           
  </div>
</div>

}
```

Any help will help me immediately as I am stuck very badly with this. Can anyone please help me with some code snippets as per my code snippet above ?

Comment: can you provide a jsbin ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bother with storing the current state of the modal, just open it and close it.  Here is my attempt (I've used this method many times, but this specific code is untested):

**HTML**, changed to do a `showModal` on button click, and removed the `ng-class` from the form:

```
<div class="pull-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-with-text" ng-click="showModal()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add New Item
  </button>
</div>
..........
<form name="createRIForm" class="form-horizontal col-sm-6">
  <div ng-controller="AddCtrl" class="modal fade" ng-include="'createNewRI.html'">
</div></form>
```

**Angular**:

```
// In the controller
$scope.showModal = function() {
    $(".modal").modal("show");
}
```

**Modal**, changed to just use `data-dismiss`:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create New Item</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- DELETED FOR BREVITY -->
</div>
```